# Android - Best Implementation of an expanding ImageView

Tags: android, dynamic, view, imageview

I have a gallery and I am trying to expand an image that the user selects. Currently what I have is a new xml layout with the ImageView (and will eventually have a close and maximize button. I add the view using an inflater and **addContentView()** but when I reload the old layout using **setContentView** I can't edit any of the views and they all go back to their default value.

Best case scenario for the scenario would be for the user to click the picture and have it launch the new layout with the ImageView and buttons on top of the layout behind it but when exited the layout returns to normal.

So I guess the question is, how would you do this? I have a very basic understanding of layout inflating and this might be a little more advanced.

Comment: Have you tried to mimic the 'overlay' effect by simply loading up the selected image (with required buttons) in a new activity with a (semi)transparent background? That way you won't have to make any changes to your 'gallery-like' layout. You could potentially have the maximize action dynamically resize the ImageView in the new activity, or even just fiish it and fire up a new activity with a 'maximized' ImageView. By the way, using fragments in this context might be worth having a look at.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing that you should try using an intent with the ACTION_VIEW action, that way other applications can handle the displaying.

Comment: Well the thing is I want it to overlay over the layout with the options to maximize or close not call a view action.